# c# type of an object when using derived class

Tags: c#, types, type-inference

Having the following code:

```
class TrxBase
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
class Trx : TrxBase
{
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}

    static void Print(TrxBase trx)
    {
        if (trx is Trx trx1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(trx1.Prop3);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("no match");
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Trx t = new Trx();
        t.Prop1 = "prop 1";
        t.Prop3 = "prop 3";

        Print(t);
    }
```

The code from above prints "prop 3". From what I knew. in the Print method, the object will be read as an TrxBase one. And if this is the case, where is the Prop3 property saved? How does the program knows that my parameter is actually an Trx object?

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what you mean and what you want

Comment: yes, but the parameter sent is of type TrxBase. and I knew that in this case, the parameter will have only properties of the TrxBase type. So how does it know that my object has a property Prop3 that at the moment, is not visible?

Comment: When you pass Trx as TrxBase, it's not like it converts Trx to the base type, it's still the derived type. This is just how C# works.

Comment: @MineR so inside the method, the paramater actually has all the properties of the derived type, but are not visible? Is there a way to get these properties without reflection?

Comment: `if (trx is Trx trx1)` It's a type check, and a cast by the looks of it. You could do `((Trx)trx).Prop3` but you would have to check if trx is of type Trx beforehand.

Comment: Yeah, you do what you did, and check if it's a derived type.

Comment: I think this is about the time you need to look up, Inheritance, Polymorphism and Casting.. I was tempted to answer, but i see this as a slippery slope (with down votes), and a mission you really have to undertake your self

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to distinguish between *compile time types* (those that e.g. determine which overload of a method to call) and *runtime types* (which are used by e.g. reflection). Whatever contortions you go through with a particular object<sup>1</sup> (casting it to a base type, etc) doesn't change the runtime type of the object.

So just because you're passing `t` to `Print` which asks for a `TrxBase`, it doesn't *change* `t` into a `TrxBase`.

And if, inside `Print`, it tests for and determines that it's a `Trx`, it's perfectly valid for it to cast it back to that type (hidden inside the pattern matching syntax) and start treating it as the type it truly is (although, of course, it *could* be a type even more derived from `Trx`.

---

Bonus reading: Eric Lippert's [Representation and Identity](https://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/)

---

<sup>1</sup>Provided you understand that reference-changing conversions give you a *new* object. This is also further explained in the bonus reading above.

Answer (score 1):

This is how C# works, when you pass derived type object to a method with parameter with base type object compiler simply takes this derived object and interprets it like it is base.

In your case you are passing derived (`Trx`) object to method with `TrxBase` parameter. So now in the scope of `Print(TrxBase trx)` , `trx` will be treated like it is `TrxBase`, but then you are using [pattern matching](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/) to determine if this `trx` can be reprsented into more derived `Trx` object type, which in your case is true, can and therefore prints `prop 3`.

It is possible to cast derived type to more base type, but the other way will result into `InvalidCastException` coming from CLR. Because if you think about it - lets say you allocate new object of type `TrxBase`, CLR allocator will allocate such object on the heap (or the stack if value type) with all the needed properties this object has. Now if you request from CLR to cast this specific object to something more specific you are ultimately requesting this specific memory layout to change into another (adding fields, properties and such from your specific object) which CLR does not support.

Comment: but in this case, pattern patching is using reflection to see that my object has a property Prop3, so it can be represented as a Trx type?

Comment: Uhhh no it's not using reflection.

Comment: @BudaGavril, no its not a reflection if you are new to C# (I assume you are), just imagine it that way: you have 10 blocks of memory for your most derived object and all its fields, properties and such. And when you decide to cast to more base object, from the moment of casting only few of these 10 blocks of memory will be accessible to you (the ones that come from base class). So it is simple matter of accessibility.